# Error fsyncing/closing/dev/sda:input/output error when I install Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, usb, hard-drive, 22.04

Hi I try to install Ubuntu 22.04 alongside Win10. After choosing normal installation I have an error

```
fsyncing/closing/dev/sda:input/output error
```

Later when I close this window I have an information

```
ubi-partman failed with exit code 10. Further information may be found in /var log/syslog. Do you want to try running this step again before continuing? If you do no, your installation mail fail entirely or may be broken
```

I have 5 discs:

- 500 GB SSD
- 2 TB SSD
- 1 TB SSD (I installed Windows on that disc)
- 8 TB HDD
- 8 TB HDD

Only on the one 1 TB SSD I used to install Windows

What is the problem?

This is small part of my log file:

```
Aug  2 13:12:38 ubuntu kernel: [    4.575804] ata1.00: irq_stat 0x40000001
Aug  2 13:12:38 ubuntu kernel: [    4.576122] ata1.00: failed command: READ DMA
Aug  2 13:12:38 ubuntu kernel: [    4.576440] ata1.00: cmd c8/00:08:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/e0 tag 29 dma 4096 in
Aug  2 13:12:38 ubuntu kernel: [    4.576440]          res 51/04:08:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/40 Emask 0x1 (device error)
Aug  2 13:12:38 ubuntu kernel: [    4.577062] ata1.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
Aug  2 13:12:38 ubuntu kernel: [    4.577384] ata1.00: error: { ABRT }
Aug  2 13:12:38 ubuntu systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Set Up Additional Binary Formats being skipped.
Aug  2 13:12:38 ubuntu kernel: [    4.578036] ata1.00: failed to enable AA (error_mask=0x1)
Aug  2 13:12:38 ubuntu kernel: [    4.578529] ata1.00: Read log 0x00 page 0x00 failed, Emask 0x1
Aug  2 13:12:38 ubuntu kernel: [    4.578835] ata1.00: NCQ Send/Recv Log not supported
Aug  2 13:12:38 ubuntu kernel: [    4.579018] ata1.00: Read log 0x00 page 0x00 failed, Emask 0x1
Aug  2 13:12:38 ubuntu systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Store a System Token in an EFI Variable being skipped.
Aug  2 13:12:38 ubuntu kernel: [    4.579319] ata1.00: NCQ Send/Recv Log not supported
Aug  2 13:12:38 ubuntu systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Commit a transient machine-id on disk being skipped.
Aug  2 13:12:38 ubuntu kernel: [    4.579505] ata1.00: Read log 0x00 page 0x00 failed, Emask 0x1
Aug  2 13:12:38 ubuntu kernel: [    4.579801] ata1.00: ATA Identify Device Log not supported
Aug  2 13:12:38 ubuntu kernel: [    4.579984] ata1.00: failed to enable Sense Data Reporting, Emask 0x1
Aug  2 13:12:38 ubuntu kernel: [    4.580598] ata1.00: failed to enable AA (error_mask=0x1)
Aug  2 13:12:38 ubuntu kernel: [    4.581082] ata1.00: Read log 0x00 page 0x00 failed, Emask 0x1
Aug  2 13:12:38 ubuntu kernel: [    4.581401] ata1.00: NCQ Send/Recv Log not supported
Aug  2 13:12:38 ubuntu systemd[1]: Starting Create Volatile Files and Directories...
Aug  2 13:12:38 ubuntu kernel: [    4.581584] ata1.00: Read log 0x00 page 0x00 failed, Emask 0x1
Aug  2 13:12:38 ubuntu kernel: [    4.581894] ata1.00: NCQ Send/Recv Log not supported
Aug  2 13:12:38 ubuntu kernel: [    4.582076] ata1.00: Read log 0x00 page 0x00 failed, Emask 0x1
Aug  2 13:12:38 ubuntu systemd[1]: Starting Uncomplicated firewall...
Aug  2 13:12:38 ubuntu systemd[1]: Finished Tell Plymouth To Write Out Runtime Data.
Aug  2 13:12:38 ubuntu systemd[1]: Received SIGRTMIN+20 from PID 565 (plymouthd).
Aug  2 13:12:38 ubuntu systemd[1]: Finished Create final runtime dir for shutdown pivot root.
Aug  2 13:12:38 ubuntu systemd[1]: Finished Uncomplicated firewall.
Aug  2 13:12:38 ubuntu systemd[1]: Reached target Preparation for Network.
Aug  2 13:12:38 ubuntu systemd[1]: Finished Create Volatile Files and Directories.
Aug  2 13:12:38 ubuntu systemd[1]: Starting Userspace Out-Of-Memory (OOM) Killer...
Aug  2 13:12:38 ubuntu systemd[1]: Starting Network Name Resolution...
Aug  2 13:12:38 ubuntu systemd[1]: Starting Network Time Synchronization...
Aug  2 13:12:38 ubuntu systemd[1]: Starting Record System Boot/Shutdown in UTMP...
Aug  2 13:12:38 ubuntu systemd[1]: Finished Record System Boot/Shutdown in UTMP.
Aug  2 13:12:38 ubuntu systemd[1]: Started Network Time Synchronization.
Aug  2 13:12:38 ubuntu systemd[1]: Reached target System Time Set.
Aug  2 13:12:38 ubuntu systemd-oomd[1876]: Swap is currently not detected; memory pressure usage will be degraded
Aug  2 13:12:38 ubuntu systemd[1]: Started Userspace Out-Of-Memory (OOM) Killer.
Aug  2 13:12:38 ubuntu kernel: [    4.582378] ata1.00: ATA Identify Device Log not supported
Aug  2 13:12:38 ubuntu kernel: [    4.582559] ata1.00: failed to enable Sense Data Reporting, Emask 0x1
Aug  2 13:12:38 ubuntu systemd-resolved[1877]: Positive Trust Anchors:
```

Comment: The kind of input/output errors you're seeing typically suggest that you have a problem with your hardware.  Device errors indicate hardware problems.  How old is the system and the disk in it?

Comment: @ThomasWard
Thank you for comment Thomas! 
I just got this computer yesterday and put an extra ssd in it. So computer and disks are new.